# How does the logstash kv{} filter plugin work?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I wanted to extract url query params and as per [this forum answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/grok-uri-extract/54836/3) I was able to do it with kv{}

But I want to understand how this works.

Here is my string: `param1=val1&param2=val2&adv=val3&param3=val4&param4=val5`

Now I have that field extracted in logstash as uri_query.

So then I use kv like this:

```
kv {
  source => "uriQuery"
  field_split => "&"
  prefix => "query_"
}
```

And I get fields for each query param:

```
query_param1 val1
query_param2 val2
etc
```

But what I don't understand is how it knows to strip out and break on the "=". Is that like the default token for kv's key=value syntax or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. `=` is the default token for kv.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-value_split) is the documentation about that parameter for the kv plugin which is called `value_split`.